# Is it possible to join two charts, one plotted with matplotlib.pyplot and the other plotted with mplfinance into the same figure. eg; same image

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplfinance

I am plotting two charts.  One bar chart with matplotlib.pyplot and a second candle chart with mplfinance and I want to show them stacked on top of one another in the same figure (image).

I have found examples of how to stack plots done with matplotlib.pyplot, but can't seem to find any examples of how to join the output of two plotting libs into a single plot.

Is this possible and if so how do I go about it?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: It seems you cannot access to ax object in using mplfinance (plot function creates its own figure and axes) and the only way to a add a chart is to use `make_addplot` function before `plot` function.

Comment: It seems to be work in progress [Issue 17](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/issues/17). Until it is fixed, you can try to save your mplfinance plot and load it as an image in matplotlib.

Comment: Thanks guys, I will do some research around your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

first Customize Axis using matplotlib
and you can adding Axis in mplfinance, use "ax" option
for example :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mplfinance as mpf
import pandas as pd


ax = plt.subplot() 

#ax.scatter(dates, somevalues)



quotes = pd.read_csv("example.csv")

mpf.plot(quotes, type="candle", ax=ax)
```

Comment: Now that mplfinance supports passing in an external axes, this is the correct answer.  However there are some subtlties regarding style (colors, fonts, etc).  I suggest carefully reading the documentaion [**here**](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/markdown/subplots.md#external-axes-method) and [**here**](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/external_axes.ipynb)